# Each thread creating different database connections depending on the tables

Tags: java, database, multithreading, connection

I am working on a project in which I need to make different database connections depending on the tables. All the tables and connection details are there in the `config.properties file`. So suppose if I have two tables with there connection details in the `config.properties` file. Then each thread will make two `database connections` whenever it will come to `run method`.

Below method will read the property files and make a `ReadTableConnectionInfo object` for each tables.

```
private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").split(" "));

    for (String arg : tableNames) {

        ReadTableConnectionInfo ci = new ReadTableConnectionInfo();

        String url = prop.getProperty(arg + ".url");
        String user = prop.getProperty(arg + ".user");
        String password = prop.getProperty(arg + ".password");
        String driver = prop.getProperty(arg + ".driver");

        ci.setUrl(url);
        ci.setUser(user);
        ci.setPassword(password);
        ci.setDriver(driver);

        tableList.put(arg, ci);
    }

}
```

Below is the class that will hold all the table connection info for a particular table.

```
public class ReadTableConnectionInfo {

    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String password;
    public String driver;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

From the below code, I am trying to execute `ReadTask class` using multiple threads by passing `tableList map` in the `constructor` and in the `run method` each thread will create two `different database connections` depending on the `tableLists size`.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    service.submit(new ReadTask(tableList));
}


public ReadTask(HashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
    this.tableLists = tableList;
}


@Override
public void run() {

    int j = 0;
    dbConnection = new Connection[tableLists.size()];
    statement = new Statement[tableLists.size()];

    //loop around the map values and make the connection list
    for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {

        dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(ci.getUrl(), ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(), ci.getDriver());
        statement[j] = dbConnection[j].createStatement();

        j++;
    }
}
```

**My question is**- Is there any better design of doing the similar problem? Like each thread should create different database connections and store it in a list, so that I can use them properly.

Comment: I think Hibernate Shards http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html its for you.. you should try it

Comment: Are there common database schemas, or all tables come in different JDBC connection strings?

Comment: They comes in different `JDBC Connection Strings`.